# Validating input with inquirer

Tags: python

I'm trying to check if the length of my input is valid like this:

```
questions = [
    inquirer.Text('b_file', message='.GBK File',
                  validate=lambda file: len(str(file))),
    inquirer.Text('e_file', message='.XLS File',
                  validate=lambda file: len(str(file)))]
```

But isn't working. Is saying that is not a valid input:

```
>>> import inquirer
>>> questions = [
...     inquirer.Text('b_file', message='.GBK File',
...                   validate=lambda file: len(str(file))),
...     inquirer.Text('e_file', message='.XLS File',
...                   validate=lambda file: len(str(file)))]
>>> answers = inquirer.prompt(questions)
[?] .GBK File: foo
>> "foo" is not a valid b_file.
```

Comment: Maybe the input isn't valid. See how to ask a [mcve].

Comment: The [`validate` documentation](http://python-inquirer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#validate) states that the function would need to take **two** arguments; the [examples](http://python-inquirer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#text-py) seem to corroborate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function used for `validate` must take **two** arguments; the first is a dictionary with previously given answers, and the second is the current answer.

The [code to handle validation](https://github.com/magmax/python-inquirer/blob/master/inquirer/questions.py#L115-L121) catches *all* exceptions and turns those into validation errors, so using a lambda with just one argument will always result in validation failing.

Make your lambda accept the answers dictionary too; you can ignore the value given:

```
questions = [
    inquirer.Text('b_file', message='.GBK File',
                  validate=lambda answers, file: len(str(file))),
    inquirer.Text('e_file', message='.XLS File',
                  validate=lambda answers, file: len(str(file)))]
```

With that change, the questions work:

```
>>> import inquirer
>>> questions = [
...     inquirer.Text('b_file', message='.GBK File',
...                   validate=lambda answers, file: len(str(file))),
...     inquirer.Text('e_file', message='.XLS File',
...                   validate=lambda answers, file: len(str(file)))]
>>> answers = inquirer.prompt(questions)
[?] .GBK File: foo
[?] .XLS File: bar
>>> pprint(answers)
{'b_file': 'foo', 'e_file': 'bar'}
```